# C++ GetName vector of objects

Tags: c++

i have this class

```
class Dados
{
    string name;
    int valor;
public:
    Dados(string n, int v) : name(n), valor(v){};
    //~dados();

    string GetName(){return name;}
    int GetValor(){return valor;}

    void SetValor(int x){valor = x;}
}
```

and this class, which basically reads a file and put the data into a vector:

```
class FileReader{

    vector<Dados> dados;

public:
    bool ReadFile(string file) {
        dados.empty();
        string fnome, ftemp;
        int fvalor;
        ifstream fich(file);
        string linha;


        if (fich.is_open())                 
        {

            while (fich.peek() != EOF){

                getline(fich, linha);

                istringstream iss(linha);

                //cout << ".";
                iss >> fnome;               
                iss >> ftemp;
                iss >> fvalor;
                dados.push_back(Dados(fnome,fvalor));
            }


            fich.close();

            return 0;

        }
        else{ 
            cout << "Ficheiro \""<< file <<"\" nao encontrado!";
            return 1;
        }
    }




    int FindOnVector(string fi)
    {
        int val;

        vector<Dados>::const_iterator it;

        it = dados.begin();
        while (it != dados.end()){

            val = it->GetValor();
            it++;
        }


        return val;
    }

};
```

But on class FileReader i need on method for find a name, and return int (valor).
This time he just doing this return value. Not this search a name.

but `val = it->GetValor();`

Give to me this error on VS 2012:

```
error C2662: 'Dados::GetValor' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Dados' to 'Dados &'
```

someon can me help?

Bests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the GetValor method const:

```
`int GetValor() const {return valor;}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the getter like this and it will work:

```
int GetValor() const {return valor;}
```

The const keyword indicates that calling GetValor does not modify the object.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question, but this is wrong:

```
while (fich.peek() != EOF)
{
    // ...
}
```

You should just have

```
while (std::getline(fich, linha))
{
    // ...
}
```

To your original question, you need a getter for name that has a const modifier:

```
string GetName() const
{
    return name;
}
```

The same goes for all your getters if you wish to use them in const functions/iterators.

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare these functions as const

```
string GetName()const {return name;}
int GetValor() const {return valor;}
```

Secondly this statement in function ReadFile

```
dados.empty();
```

has no any sense. It simply returns true if the vector is empty. I think you meant

```
dados.clear();
```

As for searching an element of the vector then it is better to use standard algorithm `std::find()`or `std::find_if`if you will use a lambda expression or a standard predicate . If you will use `std::find` you need to define operator == for class Dados.

As for your own function that you should decide what it will return in case when nothing was found. Suppose you will return 0. So the function could look the following way

```
int FindOnVector( const string &fi ) const
{
    int val = 0;


    for ( const Dados &d : dados )
    {
        if ( d.GetName() == fi )
        {
            val = d.GetValor();
            break;
        }
    }


    return val;
}
```